# Ffmpeg and noise to keep connection alive

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, internet-radio, radio, icecast

I'm trying to make SDR scanner to broadcast signal to web.

---

RTL_FM -> FFMPEG -> Icecast2.

---

But in pauses streaming terminates and as I understood, there are no options to keep it alive with Ffmpeg functions. So I decided to add empty input and mix it with RTL-signal to keep it online:

```
rtl_fm -f 104M -f 102.8 -f ... -M fm -s 180s -r 44.1k | ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44.1k:cl=mono -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 1 -i pipe:0 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 92k -ar 44.1k  -content_type audio/mpeg icecast://source:pass@localhost:8000/audio.mp3
```

Aaand it doesn't work! There is no broadcast while RTL signal is offline. Why?
Same result if I use anoisesrc instead of anullsrc.

This works as expected:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44.1k:cl=mono -acodec libvorbis -b:a 92k -ar 44.1k -content_type audio/ogg icecast://source:pass@localhost:8000/vorbis.ogg
```

apart from the fact that CPU load is 100%.

What's wrong? Maybe there is more suitable solution to keep stream alive?
*ubuntu-18.04.4*

Comment: Well, as an option  `rtl_fm -f ... | ffmpeg -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 12.5k -i pipe:0 -acodec libvorbis -ab 96k -ar 44.1k -f ogg - | cvlc - --sout '#standard{access=shout,mux=ogg,dst=source:pass@localhost:8000/audio.ogg}' --sout-keep` VLC has a solution to keep the stream alive `--sout-keep`. I can't believe what ffmpeg can't do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with another version of *rtl_fm* from here [git-hub](https://github.com/keenerd/rtl-sdr)

Just add `-E pad` and when squelch is enabled pad output with zeros